# What does "Predefined type 'System.TypedReference' is not defined or imported" mean on Metro project?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am currently converting a library to be a Metro library for Windows 8.  I've created a brand new project in Visual Studio 2012 using the "Class Library (Windows Store apps)" C# Template.  I've been adding a lot of files and working through the compile errors, but the one that's confusing me is:

```
Error   2   Predefined type 'System.TypedReference' is not defined or
imported    CSC MyNewProject
```

The "CSC" appears under the "File" column.  Double-clicking the error does nothing.  Googling only gives me this:

> - Do not specify the /nostdlib option from the command line compiler.
> - Make sure that the project refers to the correct mscorlib.dll.
> - Reinstall the .NET Framework common language runtime (if the previous
>     solutions do not solve the problem).

(source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5c3ehka.aspx)

I'm not using a command line compiler, I don't know how to include or exclude mscorlib - because unlike previous .NET apps in Visual Studio, the only thing my project references is ".NET for Windows Store apps" and "Windows" (something I'm still getting used to).

Any thoughts/advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

That Object is not available or has been relocated for the new ARM .NET architecture.

Here is the Full API for you to search, I would of searched for it, but it is missing a search func.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211369.aspx

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but this error is not tied to any source code - if it was then I would be able to fix the code that is causing the error.  This looks like...a project-level error.  So even if what you say is the case, I have no idea how to fix it.  There's no code to remove for it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who encounters this, I experienced this while I was converting a project to run on metro.  I continued to fix other issues (at the time this was one of hundreds of errors) and eventually this just simply disappeared.  My plan was to eventually compare this to a new metro project in a text editor once I fixed all the other errors, but it solved itself before that could happen.